# Godot: How do I get the id mask for a physics layer by name?

Tags: physics, godot, collider

I would like to figure out whether a [collider](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_collisionobject2d.html) is in a physics layer by the name (string) I set in project settings:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    var collision = move_and_collide(direction * delta * speed)
    if collision and (collision.collider.collision_layer & get_collision_layer("Walls")) != 0:
        direction = direction.bounce(Vector2.LEFT)
    # more behaviors based on other layer tests
```

`Walls` is the name of the physics layer and I am trying to find `get_collision_layer`.

I am using Godot 3.2.1.  `self` is a `KinematicBody2D` & colliders are `StaticBody2D`'s & also `KinematicBody2D`'s.

I have figured out the collision id (as an int) but still think it would be cleaner to use layer names, preferably using a built-in function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting layer via name is not possible as of Godot v3.2.1.

However, you can use groups and the logic will be the same. Add the wall collision objects to a "Walls" group and then check if it's in the group instead of checking the collision layer. For example:

```
    if collision and collision.collider.is_in_group("Walls"):
        direction = direction.bounce(Vector2.LEFT)
```

Comment: Groups are OK for some usages, but you often need layer bitmasks when using Godot APIs.

Answer (score 5):

Just a demo in an empty node - range starts with 1 up to the number of layers
It creates a dictionary where you can access with layer name and get the number as 2 to the power of layer number - run only once in a parent node

```
func _ready():
    var layers = {}
    for i in range(0, 5, 1):
        var layer = ProjectSettings.get_setting("layer_names/2d_physics/layer_" + str(i + 1))
        layers[layer] = pow(2, i)
    print(layers)
    print(layers['Coins'])
```

{Bumpers:16, Coins:4, Enemies:2, Player:1, World:8}

4

and  a working version

```
var is_stomping = false
var _layers := {}

func _ready():
    for i in range(0, 5, 1):
        var layer = ProjectSettings.get_setting("layer_names/2d_physics/layer_" + str(i + 1))
        _layers[layer] = pow(2, i)


func _on_StompDetector_area_entered(area: Area2D) -> void:
    is_stomping = area.collision_layer == _layers['Bumpers']
```

Comment: Neat. I went with @hola's suggestion of using groups though. At the time I had asked the question I wasn't aware of groups.

Comment: I know it was ages ago-but I had the same problem and it was said in few places that its impossible in current godot so I made it possible.